# Regex to extract across multi character delimiter

Tags: regex

I need to extract the long data format shown in the single line string below:

```
Fred,0 Dave,0 Rupert,0 Larry,1 Barry,0 Steve,1 RTE1832 : London***11.2.0.4.0***RE22/1***20170321075456***SS/D20
```

The number of names and names change so I would like to extract using a `***` delimiter. Help appreciated.

EDIT: Tried \s*\*\*\*\s* but need to get the correct group.

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Please see edit.

Comment: Would you please explain in more details what part of the input string you'd like to extract? What strings exactly you expect to be extracted from your data sample?

Comment: I would like to extract 20170321075456

Comment: So you need a substring surrounded by `***` coming after the third occurrence of `***`, don't you?

Comment: Exactly - what I have shown above in the EDIT matches all 4 separated fiields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided you need a substring surrounded by `***` coming after the third occurrence of `***`,  this regex:

```
(?:.*?\*{3}\s*){3}(.*?)\s*\*{3}
```

will fill the first capture group with the desired data.

Explanation:

- `.*?` - match anything but lazily to avoid swallowing `***`
- `\*{3}` - literally `*` three times
- `\s` - optionally followed by spaces
- `(?:.*?\*{3}\s*)` - all of the above concatenated together
- `(?:.*?\*{3}\s*){3}` - ... repeated three times
- `(.*?)` - anything (lazily again to stop on the `***` delimiter) - captured in a group
- `\s*` - optionally followed by spaces
- `\*{3}` - and the closing delimiter

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/cS2rLm/1